# Did Chinese users spend 277.4 trillion yuan ($41.51 trillion) on mobile payments in 2018?

Tags: china

According to [an article](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/331460) on Entepreneur.com:

> China had 1.2 billion unique mobile subscribers by the end of last year, making it the largest mobile market in the world. This widespread mobile ecosystem has resulted in a steep growth in mobile payments over the past five years, with transactions touching **277.4 trillion yuan ($41.51 trillion)** in 2018, which is almost 28 times more than what it was five years ago, according to a report by the country’s central bank, People’s Bank of China (PBOC).

There are multiple [other sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22277.4+trillion+yuan%22&oq=%22277.4+trillion+yuan%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.472j1j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but I cannot trace the Chinese original. Is the above number true?

Comment: That means every Chinese man, woman and child spent almost $35,000 each on-line in 2018. I'm guessing that's more than the average income. Unless the Chinese billionaires spend *really* big on-line, something's wrong here ;-)

Comment: We cannot expect news reporters to get their numbers right.  (Sorry, only anecdotal evidence.)

Comment: You can find more sources if you search for "277.39 trillion yuan".

Comment: Official source can probably [be found here](http://www.gov.cn/xinwen/2019-03/20/content_5375401.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The Chinese government document [2018年支付体系运行总体情况](http://www.gov.cn/xinwen/2019-03/20/content_5375401.htm) (linked in [nwellnhof's comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45595/did-chinese-users-spend-277-4-trillion-yuan-41-51-trillion-on-mobile-payments#comment211431_45595)) says:

> 2018年 ... 移动支付业务605.31亿笔，金额277.39万亿元 ...
> In 2018 ... [there were] mobile payment services [of] 60.531 billion transactions, [and] monetary value 277.39 trillion yuan ...

---

First, some context.

Chinese people virtually don't pay in cash anymore, they pay using their phones, typically using [WeChat](https://web.wechat.com/) (微信) and/or [Alipay](https://www.alipay.com/) (支付宝).  They also buy a lot online, using [TaoBao](https://www.taobao.com/) (淘宝), [JingDong](https://global.jd.com/) (京东), etc.

It's almost like cash is obsolete here.  This includes buying basically anything, e.g., you can buy a car, make everyday transactions, pay your rent, etc., using these services.

So, large numbers are unsurprising: it probably includes a billion people making a large proportion of their transactions this way.

My Chinese is not fantastic, but I'll attempt a translation of the relevant information in the Chinese government document linked in [nwellnhof's comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45595/did-chinese-users-spend-277-4-trillion-yuan-41-51-trillion-on-mobile-payments#comment211431_45595):

> （四）电子支付
> 4. Electronic payment
>
> 移动支付业务量快速增长。2018年，银行业金融机构共处理电子支付9业务1751.92亿笔，金额2539.70万亿元。其中，网上支付业务570.13亿笔，金额2126.30万亿元，同比分别增长17.36%和2.47%；**移动支付业务605.31亿笔，金额277.39万亿元**，同比分别增长61.19%和36.69%；电话支付业务1.58亿笔，金额7.68万亿元，同比分别下降0.99%和12.54%。
>
> Mobile payment business rapidly increased in quantity.  2018 banking and finance dealt with electronic payments [by] 9 services [of] 175.192 billion transactions, [and] monetary value 2,539.70 trillion yuan.  Among these, online payment business [of] 57,013 billion transactions, [and] monetary value 2,126.30 trillion yuan, [and] over this period, respective growth [of] 17.36% and 2.47%; **mobile payment services [of] 60.531 billion transactions, [and] monetary value 277.39 trillion yuan**, [and] over this period, respective growth [of] 61.19% and 36.69%; telephone payment service [of] 158 million translations, [and] monetary value 7.68 trillion yuan, [and] over this period a respective decline [of] 0.99% and 12.54%.
>
> <sub>2018年支付体系运行总体情况 *2018 Payment System Operation Overall Situation* ([pdf](http://www.gov.cn/xinwen/2019-03/20/5375401/files/1e1a87e02453432ab032ae5187b7804a.pdf))</sub>

Here:

- 1 billion = 1,000 million = 1,000,000,000
- 100 million = 1亿
- 1 trillion = 1,000 billion = 1万亿

Comment: But how could Chinese consumers spend four times more on mobile payments than the GDP of China ($12 trillion as of 2018)? By its very definition the GDP should cover every product sold within China.

Comment: I guess the answer to that is many transactions are not "payments".

Comment: To me that does not seem to make much sense. As @JonathanReez said that total value of payments cannot be higher than GDP. So even if many transactions were not payments the total value should not be as high. I think the answer should include this contradiction.

Comment: It is possible. Consider for example gifts (CNY, birthdays, festivals) - an ordinary Chinece would gift money to many people, and receive monetary gifts from them. At the end of the day, he spent $2000 and received roughly $2000 - so it is total $4000 in online payment transactions, but he is in the same position financially. Note that online payments between people are comission-free in China.